# Is there a version of the 74HC154 with active High rather than active Low?

Tags: integrated-circuit

I'm looking for a 4-to-16 decoder IC, but I'm looking for an active High similar to the 3-to-8 decoder M74HC238. Seems all the ones I'm finding are active High.

Comment: may I remind that "*Questions seeking recommendations for specific products are off-topic [...]*"

Comment: I disagree - this falls under "a specific electronics design problem" since outputs of incorrect polarity will require additional glue logic. I believe the intent of not permitting product recommendations is to avoid questions like "which model of CD player is best"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is none. Connect two '238s together by joining an enable input of one and an inhibit input of the other as the fourth bit.

Comment: Sorry, that won't work. Since what he wants is a 154 with a high enable, that means 4 address bits and a single high enable. You can use 2 138s, with one low enable tied to one high enable as the 4th address bit, but that leaves only low enables on the 138 which used the high enable as the address bit. Sorry.

Comment: That's what '04s (or '00s) are for.

Comment: Sure. But if Justin were willing  to use an inverter, he wouldn't have asked his question, now would he?

Comment: Using one inverter may be acceptable. Using 16 is not.

Comment: My apologies. Due to an apparent brain fart, I somehow thought he wanted high enable, rather than high outputs. Some days.....

Answer (score 1):

The 74HC4514 for active-high and the 74HC4515 for active-low.